# how to create a markers zoom animation when is created?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

I would like create effect described in the title on my markers when they are added. I see for ios exists method `marker.appearAnimation` but nothing similar for android. Now I will just add a BitmapDescription to MarkerOptions

```
final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(pos)
                            .icon(getIconForCluster(new BitmapDescriptor(getObjectWrapped()))
            );
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `animateCamera()` method from GoogleMaps object.
Example:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(()
            -> mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newLatLngZoom(mMapBoundary.getCenter(), 17)));
```

with `mMapBoundary` is a LatLngBounds object. you can set the markers position here, and 17 is the zoom level.

Comment: I do not intend to animate the camera, but the marker